# How can I get a date from mysql database if it is not null?

Tags: mysql, datetime, null

I want to select the value birthday from my database table.
If it is not null the output should be a date. But if it is null, then the output should be empty.

```
    'SELECT *,
    case when isnull(mydate) then null else date_format(mydate, cats.bithday,"%d.%m.%y") end as birthday;
    FROM cats 
    LEFT JOIN dogs ON cats.dogs=dogs.id'
```

I get an error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in
>   the call to native function 'date_format'

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *, ifnull(cats.bithday,'') as cats_birthday
FROM cats 
LEFT JOIN dogs ON cats.dogs=dogs.id
```

Result:

```
case (birthday is null)
    cats_birthday = ''
case (birthday is not null)
    cats_birthday = db-value
```

Comment: So this means I write it like this: `ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(cats.birthday,"%d.%m.%y"),' ') AS cats_birthday`

Answer (score 0):

You are giving date_format three parameters, but it only expects two.

See the [MySQL docs here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

> DATE_FORMAT(date,format)